# Backup iPhone contacts etc to move to new iPhone (no iCloud)

Tags: iphone, backup

I have three iPhones linked to my AppleID. (Don't ask me why, it began when Apple was not providing family access.) I already have iCloud Contacts, Calendars, etc. on my AppleID made from one of my iPhones.

Now I'm going to replace my another iPhone (which doesn't use iCloud Contacts and Calendars) with new one, and need to backup and move contacts and other stuff. Since I don't want to merge Contacts and Calendars, I can't use iCloud on the iPhone I want to backup.

Is it possible to change AppleID on the iPhone I want to backup keeping all the stuff untouched to link it to new iCloud account? Or is there another way?

Comment: Approximately how many contacts are we dealing with?

Comment: Do you have anything enabled in Settings > iCloud on the iPhone you're looking to replace?

Comment: @Nikita it seems no

Comment: @PinchusGelbman 100-150

Comment: You won't lose any contacts then, just make a local backup of your iPhone, replace it, restore to a new device, change AppleID you use for stores/messages etc. and enable iCloud (or don't). If it's a fresh account it will just sync all relevant data on the phone to iCloud.

Comment: @Nikita as far as I know the local backup doesn't backup contacts, calendar, reminders. Or am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1):

## Switching Apple IDs

If you go to Settings > iCloud and Sign Out, everything **should** stay safely on your phone with the exception of iCloud Drive documents and photos from your Photo Library. If you were to then sign into a different Apple ID, such as a newly created one, you could turn things like Contacts and Calendars. I say should because if you get any warnings saying something will be deleted, you should take them seriously.

Unfortunately , this requires taking extra precautions for iCloud Photo Library and iCloud Drive. If you do have things in iCloud Drive or iCloud Photo Library, you can go to www.icloud.com on a computer and perhaps download your documents and photos from there so that they are safe on a computer.

## The Alternative

Contacts and Calendars are a tricky thing to backup without iCloud as they don't seem to be included in the catch-all iCloud Backup.
There may be many alternatives to the above, but the only one I thought of off the top of my head was to check with your carrier about using your SIM card for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free app available in the App Store called [My Contacts Backup](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8) which backs up all your contacts (free version is limited to 500 contacts) into a VCF file which you could then use to import in [icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/#contacts) by clicking on the Cog Wheel on the bottom left corner in the Contacts section and then clicking on the *Import vCard...* option from that menu.

Personally I've never used the above mentioned app but its App Store reviews seems to be phenomenal.

About switching Apple ID's that might be an option but you'll want to make sure to first setup your primary iCloud account if you'd like to use the rest of the iCloud features like iCloud Drive, Photos, Notes, Mail, Etc. and then add your new account which you'd like to use only for Contacts by adding that account by pressing the Add Account within the Mail settings and on that one select only Contacts (while on your primary you'll leave contacts turned off).